# Define variable in list comprehension format function

Tags: list, haskell

I have this pseudocode that calculates the factorial of a number given by the user.

```
Process without_title
     Define i, tmp, x As Integers;
     tmp<-1;
     Write "Enter a number to calculate its factorial";
     Read x;
     For i <- 1 Until x Do
         tmp<-tmp * i;
     EndTo
     Write tmp;
EndProcess
```

Now I would like to implement the same code in Haskell using list comprehensions

```
import Data.IORef

factorial::Int -> Int
factorial x = [tmp|i<-[1..x], modifyIORef tmp (*i)]
```

Throws error saying `tmp` variable not defined

How do I define the `tmp` variable, so that I can use it?

Comment: Why is your code to calculate a factorial handling input at all? Typically this would be a pure function, and IO would be handled separately. It looks like you're trying to implement something very imperative, and that's not especially "Haskell-y."

Comment: If the result is an integer, hence not a list, you can't generate it using a list comprehension. Use a fold instead (I'd try a `foldl'` here). Or `product [1..n]`, but that would invalidate the point of the exercise, I guess.

Comment: You had a good insight in transliterating imperative statements like `tmp *= i;` and `return tmp;` into `modifyIORef tmp (*i)` and `tmp` respectively. In the same imperative style, the direct answer to your question would be to phrase `var tmp = 1;` as `tmp <- newIORef 1`. However, this imperative logic is the real source of your problem: a list comprehension can’t combine these statements into a solution; and a purely functional solution, without `IORef`, is much simpler anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement the existing answers: a problem is that if you start involving IO, you cannot have an IO-free type signature like `factorial :: Int -> Int` for your function.

Another (easier to deal with) problem is that if you return a list comprehension expression *directly*, the result type of your function has to be some sort of list. It cannot be a scalar value such as `Int`.

A possible compromise is to use the Haskell [*state monad*](https://wiki.haskell.org/State_Monad), with the `tmp` product as the state. You can generate the list of required multiplication operations with a suitable list comprehension expression, and then combine them using the [`sequence_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:sequence_) library function.

Like this:

```
import  Control.Monad.State (state, runState, sequence)

factorial :: Int -> Int
factorial x = finalTmp  where
    tmp0           = 1  -- our initial state
    actions        = [ state (\tmp -> ((), i*tmp)) | i <- [1..x] ]
    (rs, finalTmp) = runState  (sequence_ actions)  tmp0
```

using `tmp` as the state as per your notations, even though using `st` would be more idiomatic.

Answer (score 3):

To implement a factorial function using a mutable `IORef` like this you will need to work in the IO monad and use a `newIORef` operation to create your `IORef` and then use `forM_`, `traverse_`, or `sequence_` or a similar function to sequence a set of IO operations on that `IORef`.  It might look something like:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.IORef

factorial :: Int -> IO Int
factorial x = do
  tmp <- newIORef 1
  forM_ [1..x] $ \i -> modifyIORef' tmp (*i)
  readIORef tmp
```

or, if you prefer to use a list comprehension so it looks a little more like your attempt above, something like:

```
import Data.IORef

factorialIO :: Int -> IO Int
factorialIO x = do
  tmp <- newIORef 1
  sequence_ [modifyIORef' tmp (*i) | i <- [1..x]]
  readIORef tmp
```

(Using the strict `modifyIORef'` provides better performance than the lazy `modifyIORef`.)

This can then be called like so:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  result <- factorial 10
  print $ result
```

This will generally be slower than a more direct, "pure" solution like:

```
factorial :: Int -> Int
factorial x = product [1..x]
```

My benchmarks suggest that the `IORef`-based version is about two times slower than the pure `product`-based version.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is very *un*-Haskellish to work with mutating variables. This is one of the reasons that you will need to work with `IO Ref`s: since the ref itself does not change, and modifying its value is seen as a side-effect.

If you thus want to implement the factorial manually, recursion is used as way to repeat a certain task, and by passing different values to the parameter can be seen as performing this iteration with modified values, so:

```
factorial::Int -> Int
factorial 0 = 1
factorial n = n * (factorial (n-1))
```

But since Haskell has some higher level utility functions, we can for example generate a list of items, and then determine the product of these.